# VueJS - function in import js file not getting triggered

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

We are building a web application using Vue JS and PHP, we are new to Vue JS. The server-side execution is fine, the API is able to fetch data as JSON. While trying out a static array display before making the API call, we find that the function in imported "app.js" is not getting called and the table displayed is empty. Please let us know what we might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const MY_CONST = 'Vue.js';
export let memberList = new Vue({
    el: '#members',
    data: {
        members: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getAllMembers();
    },

    methods: {
        getAllMembers: function () {
            /*
            axios.get("https://xxxxxx.com/services/api.php")
                .then(function (response) {
                    memberList.members = response.data.members;
                });
            */
            memberList.members = [{ "empname": "Dinesh Dassss" },
                                  { "empname": "Kapil Koranne" }];
        }
    }
});
```

---

This is the Vue component. The members object is empty.

```
<script>
    import * as mykey from './app.js'
    export default {
        name: 'Home',
        props: {
            msg: String
        },
        data() {
            return {
                message: `Hello ${mykey.MY_CONST}!`,
                members: mykey.memberList.members
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: console in mounted works or not?

Comment: Why are you exporting a `Vue` instance as `memberList`? That doesn't make much sense and you shouldn't directly access `data` properties like that either

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **this** reference for current instance reference:

```
getAllMembers: function () {
          var me = this;
            /*
            axios.get("https://xxxxxx.com/services/api.php")
                .then(function (response) {
                  // direct this not works here but we have 
                 //saved this in another variable and scope of a var is there 
                    me.members = response.data.members;
                });
            */
          // this reference works fine here.
            this.members = [{ "empname": "Dinesh Dassss" },
                          { "empname": "Kapil Koranne" }];
        }
```

Comment: Why bother with creating a `me` variable? Just use `this.members`

Comment: Neha, I am facing an issue with the "axios.get" call. Would you be able to ping me directly, I can share with you the issue.

Comment: this keyword works only in local function. it works fine until you use like  me.members = response.data.members; but when you try to use it inside ajax function it takes reference of that function. so to use it inside ajax function we need to save reference of this in another variable.

Comment: Or just use an arrow function ~ `axios.get(...).then(response => { ... })`

Comment: When I enabled the "axios.get" call now, I got the error "axios is not defined". So I imported it as "import axios from './axios.js';" But now get the error "export 'default' (imported as 'axios') was not found in './axios.js'. Please help.